# How can I reverse the 'fn' key on an Apple Keyboard so that F1, F2, F3... are used as default?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

To be more clear, right now the volume and brightness keys are used and I have to hold <kbd>Fn</kbd> in order to execute an <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd>, <kbd>F4</kbd>, <kbd>F5</kbd>... command. Can I reverse this so it's function key by default and holding <kbd>Fn</kbd> enables the volume and other special controls?

Comment: Are you looking for a per-user or system-wide setting?

Comment: Could you specify what sort of keyboard this is; a stand-alone Apple USB keyboard, or something built into a laptop? This will help others with the same question find it more easily.

Comment: https://pwr.github.io/Solaar/ this is the solution

Answer (score 135, accepted):

This is described on the Ubuntu Community Wiki:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard#Change_Function_Key_behavior

You can try:

```
sudo bash -c "echo 2 > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode"
```

If it works you can change this permanently (per the linked wiki page):

```
echo options hid_apple fnmode=2 | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
sudo reboot # optional
```

Comment: That link you posted is quite a lot to read. To help future users get to the permanent solution (that doesn't get undone after each reboot) faster, here's the 3 commands you need to type to make this permanent, per the link you posted above: 1) `echo options hid_apple fnmode=2 | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf`, 2) `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all`, 3) (optional) `sudo reboot`. Done! Works for me on my 2008 white MacBook running Xubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: can confirm that it works on MacBook Air 2015 with 16.04 on it

Comment: can confirm that it works on MacBook Pro 2015 with 19.04 on it

Comment: worked with Ubuntu 18.04 and the Apple numeric pad wired keyboard

Comment: Not only does this work with Apple keyboards, but also apparently any keyboard that uses the same controller, such as the Varmilo VA87M: https://forums.servethehome.com/index.php?threads/varmilo-keyboard-fn-keys-under-linux.29041/

Comment: You, Sir, are a life saver! :-)

Comment: Confirmed on Ubuntu 22.04, Dell XPS 15

Answer (score 4):

please try this when editing directly fnmode fails.

`echo 2 | sudo tee /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode`

Answer (score 0):

On older Apple laptop hardware, this is accomplished by a configuration setting of [PBButtonsd](http://pbbuttons.berlios.de/projects/pbbuttonsd/index.html).  You would need to add this line to [the config file /etc/pbbuttonsd.conf](http://pbbuttons.berlios.de/projects/pbbuttonsd/man-pbbuttonsd.cnf.html):

```
KBDMode = fkeysfirst
```

PBButtonsd works on iBooks and PowerBooks (PowerPC-based) and MacBooks (Intel-based); the native Ubuntu package seems to have disappeared after Dapper Drake

Comment: Actually I'm running a Thinkpad T510, I just love these aluminum Apple keyboards.

Answer (score 0):

it may also be worthwhile to check your BIOS options for this feature. On my Dell Inspiron, this can be set through the BIOS. Hopefully it'll work for your hardware too.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to access to the BIOS for Mac. This is Apple approach