# Apple Magic Keyboard A2449 (Touch ID) has wrong Fn key assignment

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, 22.04

Recently bought a Magic Keyboard with Touch ID and white it connects normally, the Fn key is poorly mapped and I don't know how to fix it.

Pressing the Key works as brightness down and when I set the `fnmode=2` it started working as media control Play/Pause. The other F-keys don't work either. Most of them register as `~` (tilde).

None of the existing posts about using `hid_apple` on the internet solve this. The reason is twofold: There is no `/sys/module/hid_apple` on my system and probably the fact this keyboard changed its layout.

Has anyone experienced this managed to solve it? I also heard there are some works in the making in the kernel to support this keyboard.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you get this fixed?

Comment: I'm currently using an Apple Magic Keyboard (Touch ID) with Ubuntu 22 on a Dell XPS, and following [that solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/7553/258432) to have fn behave as F1, F2, F3.. worked for me (also went into the BIOS to change the "default fn lock" setting). You say «poorly mapped» and «don't work», but it's not clear whether you want to use "media" behavior, or "F..." behavior.

Comment: There has a been few months, perhaps the Kernel support is now a  thing. At the time, I would be okay with any, if it just worked. The problem at the time was keys being mapped to totally different keys (F2 brightness or Play/Pause).