# Activate `hid_apple` on macbook

Tags: 22.04, macbook

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my intel macbook pro (2017).

Now i want to customize the keyboard layout a bit, like making [the function keys work by default](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7537/how-can-i-reverse-the-fn-key-on-an-apple-keyboard-so-that-f1-f2-f3-are-us)

But when I try to follow these instructions, I find that `hid_apple` is not installed/running:

```
$ sudo bash -c "echo 2 > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode
>> bash: line 1: /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode: No such file or directory
```

I even tried to install [this patched version](https://github.com/free5lot/hid-apple-patched) manually but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out `hid_apple` was renamed to `applespi`.

`echo 2 | sudo tee /sys/module/applespi/parameters/fnmode`